# Oracle 10g and Oracle 12G: Why is Oracle Public link destroying characters?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle12c

I have oracle 10g and oracle 12c

We have public link in 10g and accessing table in 12c.

It is not displaying - (hyphen) correctly.

[image]

Comment: Do the databases have different charactersets?

Comment: Old one has ISO8859 and new one has UTF8. But Hyphen?

Comment: Are you sure that the character in the bottom of the screenshot is definitely a hyphen? and not something like an en dash? Have you checked the ASCII code for that character being reported by the database?

Comment: @EJEgyed: Not db guy, can you suggest how to verify that?

Comment: @fatherazrael - you can do `select dump(unitname, 1016) from ... where ...` to see the raw data stored for a specific ID, including the character set. Might be worth running locally and over the link to compare.

Comment: Yeah, this is almost certainly not an 0x2D, because it's the same in both character sets. It must be some extended character.